# How to calculate lim inf and lim sup for given sequence of sets

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, optimization

Let the indicator function be defined as $$I(x) \triangleq \begin{cases} 1, & \quad x \geq 0 \\ 0, & \quad x < 0 \end{cases}$$ and $I_{\nu}(x) \in [0,1]$ be a *continuous* approximation of the $I(x)$ such that $$\lim_{\nu \rightarrow \infty} I_{\nu}(x) = I(x), \quad \forall x$$ $$\lim_{x \rightarrow - \infty} I_{\nu}(x) = 0, \quad \forall \nu$$ $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} I_{\nu}(x) = 1, \quad \forall \nu.$$

Let us define the sequence of *connected* sets $\{ C_{\nu} \}$, where each $C_{\nu}$ is the set of values assumed by $I_{\nu}(x)$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ (hence, each element of $C_{\nu}$ belongs to $[0,1]$).

How do I calculate $\liminf_{\nu \rightarrow +\infty} C_{\nu}$ and $\limsup_{\nu \rightarrow +\infty} C_{\nu}$?

My intuition is that $\liminf_{\nu \rightarrow +\infty} C_{\nu} = \limsup_{\nu \rightarrow +\infty} C_{\nu}=\{0,1\}$, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Yes, I will remove my comments.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I_n(x)$ be $0$ for $x \le -1/n$ and $1$ for $x \ge 1/n$. On $[-/n,0]$ define $I_n(x)$ as
$$f_n(x)=n^n(1-1/n)(x+1/n)^n,$$
and on $[0,1/n]$ define it as
$$g_n(x)=1-n^{n-1}(1/n-x)^n.$$
One can check that $f_n(0)=g_n(0)=1-1/n$ and that $f(-1/n)=g(1/n)=0,$ so that the rules are not in conflict at interval endpoints and this piecewise function $I_n(x)$ is continuous, so its range is all of $[0,1].$ Furthermore for fixed negative $x$ eventually $I_n(x)=0$ (as soon as $-1/n\ge x$) and similarly for fixed positive $x$ eventually $I_n(x)=1.$ Since at $0$ itself we have $I_n(x)=1-1/n$ we have $\lim_{n \to \infty}I_n(0)=1$ as required.

So this is an example wherein the sequence $C_n$ of sets is the constant sequence each term being the interval $[0,1].$ I wasn't familiar with lim inf /sup of sets but looked it up on Wiki, and for a constant sequence $A,A,\cdots$ each of lim sup and lim inf is just $A$, so that this example shows these limits may be all ofr $[0,1]$, rather than the two point set $\{0,1\}$ mentioned in the post.

**Edit:** A much simpler $I_n(x)$ sequence: $0$ for $x<-1/n,$ linear from $0$ to $1-1/n$ on $[-1/n,0],$ then linear from $1-1/n$ to $1$ on $[0,1/n],$ and $1$ for $x>1/n$. The above definition was made when I thought one would need the high powers in order to ensure the right properties, but these follow from the shrinking domain $[-1/n,1/n]$ on which $I_n$ is not $0$ or $1$.

Comment: So that means that, even if $\lim_{\nu \to \infty} I_{\nu}(x) = I(x)$, the sequence $\{ I_{\nu} \}$ converges to the constant sequence, i.e., converges to $[0,1]$?

Comment: @ItaAtz You're right in last comment, but keep in mind my answer is only an example, showing that the sequence $C_\nu$ [not $I_\nu$ as in your comment, which I assume was a typo] in some cases may have lim inf = lim sup = $[0,1]$. In such cases where lim inf = lim sup I think the notation allows one to drop the inf/sup and just say lim $C\nu$ = $[0,1]$ in this case.

Comment: Sorry, it was actually a typo. Yes, I know that, when lim inf = lim sup, we can just talk about the limit (and drop inf/sup). My question was more about the possibility of the sequence $\{ C_{\nu} \}$ converging to the (disconnected) set $\{0,1\}$ instead to $[0,1]$.

Comment: The sequence $C_{\nu}$ can converge to the set $\{0,1\}$ by the even simpler example of defining $I_n(x)=I(x)$ for each $n=1,2,3...$ which has your desired properties, and each has the same range $C_{\nu}=\{0,1\}$ making the limit $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear: the sets $C_{\nu}$ must be all connected, i.e., intervals of $[0,1]$. I've edited the text to avoid confusion.

Comment: @ItaAtz If you specify that each $C_v$ must be connected, that is an additional assumption to the three limit statements about the approximations $I_{\nu}$ which would force each of their ranges to be an interval, and then it would follow easily that in all such examples the limit of the $C_{\nu}$ would be the interval $[0,1]$ as happened in my example.