# Lower semicontinuity of indicator function

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization

For any set $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{N}$, let us define the indicator function $$\delta_{\mathcal{S}}(\mathbf{x}) \triangleq \begin{cases}
0, & \quad \textrm{if } \mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{S} \\
\infty, & \quad \textrm{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

Is this function lower semicontinuous? I suppose it is if the set $\mathcal{S}$ is closed, but I'm not absolutely sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right.
Lower semicontinuity is equivalent to:
$$
\forall x \ \ \ \{ y| \delta_S(y)\le x
\}
$$is closed.

Let us prove this from OP's definition:

$\delta_S$ is lsc iff $\forall x\  \liminf_x  \delta_S = \delta_S(x)$

- if $\liminf_x  \delta_S = \delta_S(x)$, then let 
  $(y_n)\in \{ y| \delta_S(y)\le x\}^{\Bbb N}$ a convergent sequence.
  $$
  \delta_S(y_n)\le x\\
  $$and as $n\to\infty$:
  $$
  \delta_S(y) = \liminf \delta_S(y_n) \le x \\
  $$
  so $\{ y| \delta_S(y)\le x\}^{\Bbb N}$ is closed.
- if $\forall x \ \ \ \{ y| \delta_S(y)\le x\}$ is closed:
  let $x_n \to x$ a sequence such as $\delta_S(x_n)\to  \liminf_x \delta_S $.
  For $u$ close enough to $x\in \{ y| \delta_S(y)> \delta_S(x) - r\}$ which is an open set, 
  $$ \delta_S(u)> \delta_S(x) - r
  \\
  \liminf \delta_S = \lim \delta_S(x_n) \ge  \delta_S(x) - r
  $$
  so $$
  \liminf \delta_S\ge  \delta_S(x)
  $$
  and there is equality (the other inequality is always true).

Here this set is $\emptyset$ or $S$, so lower semicontinuity is equivalent to: $S$ is closed.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please add a reference that I can use for this statement?

Comment: This is actually the definition of semicontinuity I know. What's yours?

Comment: I know that some function $f$ is lsc on $\mathcal{S}$ if $\liminf_{x \to \bar{x}}=f(\bar{x})$, $\forall \bar{x} \in \mathcal{S}$.

Comment: I made the edit.

Comment: Thanks, now it's more clear. Perhaps you'd like to take a look at this other questions of mine: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701978/how-to-calculate-lim-inf-and-lim-sup-for-given-sequence-of-sets http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704387/epi-convergence-to-indicator-function