# Is the indicator function of a closed set prox-bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, variational-analysis

The indicator function of a closed set $C \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined as bellow:
$$
\delta_{C}(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 \quad \quad\,\, x \in C\\
+ \infty \quad x \notin C\\
\end{cases}.
$$

**Question**

Is the indicator function of a closed set prox-bounded?

**Prox-boundedness[Exercise 1.24 of [Variational analysis](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ertr/papers/rtr169-VarAnalysis-RockWets.pdf)]**

A proper, lower semi-continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty\}$ is prox-bounded if for some $r \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)+\frac{1}{2}r \|x\|^2$ is bounded from below.

**My try**

According to [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706671/lower-semicontinuity-of-indicator-function) the indicator function of a closed set is lower semi-continuous but I am not sure whether it is proper. If we let $f(x):=\delta_{C}(x)$ we need to show $\delta_{C}(x)+\frac{1}{2}r \|x\|^2$ is lower bounded for some fixed $r$ which looks like it is since the lower bound of both is zero.

Comment: Yes and specifically $r_C=0$ realizes the condition for all $C$.

Comment: According to that definition, any function that is bounded below is pox bounded.